# Whats the best way to resize all the elements in the silverlight canvas on resize?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, transform

I just started learning SL. I have tried to resize all the elements inside the canvas on its resize. But i cant find the right way.

this is what i did

1. Iterate throgh the all child elements in canvas
2. calaculate the scale X & Y based on the new size
3. And multiply the scale values with each elements size properties

But in SL3.0 i dont find any size properties in UIelement to set the new size. below the sample code

```
    private void testCanvas_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var scaleX = e.NewSize.Width / e.PreviousSize.Width;
        var scaleY = e.NewSize.Height / e.PreviousSize.Height;

        for (int i = 0; i < testCanvas.Children.Count; i++)
        {
            UIElement ui = testCanvas.Children[i];
            // but no ui.width or ui.height
        }
    }
```

Also i cant able to find an option to move each element to the new position relative to the size changed canvas...

can someone point me the right direction..

**Update:**

I wanted to achieve something like this in [MSCUI](http://www.mscui.net/PatientJourneyDemonstrator/PrimaryCare.htm) .. For more clarity i have added some screenshots

This is how initial screen looks.
[alt text http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/4611/initial.jpg](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/4611/initial.jpg)

And on expanding widget, it gets zoomed and other widgets shrink

[alt text http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/8725/afterexpand.jpg](http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/8725/afterexpand.jpg)

I only need to do the zooing part. any ideas??

Comment: The details of the true layout characteristics you want are a little sketchy you might consider adding some more detail to the question.  For example does the canvas contain scrollable text items? If so should those items simple show more text or should the size of the text grow?  Do you want the items distances from the borders of the canvas to grow or remain the same and the items area only grow?

Comment: @Anthony, added some more info, pls check out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSCUI demo is built by Martin grayson and he has published his Drag Dock control here: http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/ (there are also now some other TileView controls available now from Telerik and Infragistics that also perform the same cool layout functions). However by default this does not support automatic content resizing.

Luckily there is a new control in the November 2009 Toolkit: **ViewBox** that will do what you need with minimal code.

There is a demo of this at http://silverlight.net/content/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html. The ViewBox demo is at the bottom of the menu on the left.

Toolkit can be downloaded from http://silverlight.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=36060

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resizing the elements yourself, you should put them in a grid and let the size of the elements be relative to the size of the cell (i.e. set margins on the element). When the grid is resized, the elements are moved and resized.

Comment: thanks Guffa..  But thr problem is the control which am designing not an ordered one (not like row,column).. it is difficult arrang them in a grid.. anyway i ll try that...

Comment: @Ramesh: Yes, I understand that, as it was a day between your comment and the downvote. The question is intended for whoever it was...

Answer (score 0):

Use the GetLeft(), GetRight(), GetTop() and GetBottom() methods passing the child UIElement.

```
private void testCanvas_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var scaleX = e.NewSize.Width / e.PreviousSize.Width;
    var scaleY = e.NewSize.Height / e.PreviousSize.Height;

    for (int i = 0; i < testCanvas.Children.Count; i++)
    {
        UIElement ui = testCanvas.Children[i];

        double left = Canvas.GetLeft(ui);
        double top = Canvas.GetTop(ui);
        double right = Canvas.GetRight(ui);
        double bottom = Canvas.GetBottom(ui);
    }
}
```